# Parse multiple doubles from string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What's the simplest/cleanest way to parse multiple doubles from a string (entered in a UITextView) in Swift and put them into an array of Doubles?

Let's say, the user enters "23.4 45 16.997 -32".  As he enters it, I want

```
doubleArray[0] = 2
doubleArray[0] = 23
doubleArray[0] = 23.
doubleArray[0] = 23.4
doubleArray[1] = 4
doubleArray[1] = 45
```

etc.

I have

```
var dataArray = [""]
dataArray = inputString.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

which works fine in separating the data into an array of strings, each of which which I can then convert to Doubles.  But is there a cleaner more concise way?

Also, is there a way to easily validate the data going into the UITextView in real time?  For example, not allowing multiple decimal points or negative signs in an entry, no letters, etc.?

Right now I am using

```
let decimalPoint = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator! as String
let validChars : Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", decimalSeparator[0], " "]
```

and

```
validChar = Set(inputString).isSubset(of: validChars)
If !validChar {
    inputString.deleteBackward()
    //display Error Message
}
```

Of course this also requires ensuring there wasn't already a decimal point or a negative sign...etc.  All simple steps, but is there not something simpler?!?  (This is also considerably simplified - I actually have specific error messages such as "only one decimal separator allowed", "Invalid character", etc.)

(I have also played around with NSNumber in other contexts, but not sure how/if I can use that here.)

I feel like I'm trying to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186076/discussion-on-question-by-greg-parse-multiple-doubles-from-string-in-swift).

Answer (score 2):

Combining Leo's and Martin's answers:

```
let arrayOfDoubles = "This costs US$ 7.99"
  .components(separatedBy:.whitespacesAndNewlines)
  .compactMap{Double($0)}
```

Should work and handle multiple kinds of white space like space, non-breaking space, tabs, and newlines.

According to Martin R, it won't handle different number formatting for locales.

You could add a NumberFormatter to the mix:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")

let arrayOfDoubles = "7 3,4 12,2 9 2,3"
    .components(separatedBy:.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    .compactMap{ formatter.number(from: $0).map { $0.doubleValue } }

print(arrayOfDoubles)
```

(The example above is written to handle German format numbers, with comma decimal separators.)

However, if you are dealing with a fixed number format for sending/receiving to a server that might not matter.

Comment: @MartinR, You're German, right? Do you know if `Double.init?(String:)` handles European-formatted decimals with a "," decimal separator? I would hope so, but I'm not certain.

Comment: No, it does not. You'll need a NumberFormatter or a Scanner (with appropriately set locale).

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `UITextView` and override `textViewDidChange` method as follow:

```
import UIKit

class NumbersTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        delegate = self
    }
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // avoids a break line as the first character
        if text == "\n" {
            text = ""
            return
        }
        // avoids more than one period in a row
        if text.hasSuffix("..") {
            text!.removeLast()
        }
        // removes all invalid characters
        text!.removeAll {
            !("0"..."9" ~= $0) &&
            $0 != "\n" &&
            $0 != "."
        }
        // then check if the string ends in newLine
        // filter the doubles
        // map them into strings
        // join the numbers with newline separator
        if text.hasSuffix("\n") {
            text = text.byWords
                .compactMap { Double($0) }
                .map{ String($0) }
                .joined(separator: "\n")
            // adds the line break back to the string
            text! +=  "\n"
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {
    var byWords: [SubSequence] {
        var byWords: [SubSequence] = []
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, _ in
            byWords.append(self[range])
        }
        return byWords
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to allow different decimal separators based on the users locale as mentioned by Martin R on comments you can use NumberFormatter https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tlxnjraf32wedt/Number%20List.zip?dl=1

Comment: What is the advantage of your `byWords` extension vs using `.components(separatedBy:.whitespacesAndNewlines)` as suggested by Martin? His approach seems simpler.

Comment: @DuncanC it will also remove punctuation

Comment: Gotcha. For cases where you're parsing sentences with punctuation that would be useful. Is it smart enough to remove periods or commas from the ends of words but leave them if they are decimal separators?

Comment: Yes it would leave the period in cases like 25.0 it identifies that as a number (word).

Comment: It seems I should be able to use: 

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool .

But I can not figure out how...  (Did I mention that I am very new to Swift?)

I see a million references to it, but not one example of it in use.